# Google Play update uninstalling and reinstalling app?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-play

I have an app in the Google Play store and have gotten a couple of reports from users that when they do an update their data goes missing.

User-added data is all stored in a SQLite database in the app's sandbox.  The updates in question have no SQLite schema changes.  Once the update is done, the SQLite database appears to have no data, which is the same state as if someone installed the app fresh.

My clue that an uninstall/reinstall may be happening is that one user reported seeing the app's welcome dialog (which sets a shared preference after being displayed so it is never displayed again) right before he noticed his data missing.

So is there any case in which an update from the Play store would uninstall and then reinstall an app?  I'm not counting out that this could be an app bug- but I can't reproduce it so just want to explore this avenue too.

Thanks!

Comment: Try yourself in your own device Install manually (not from google play) use it then install (update) also manually in your device!

Comment: Have already tried this many times with every permutation of switching database versions and trying to simulate runtime errors I could think of.  There are only 2 users out of 1000s who have reported this, but both reports are similar and based on their descriptions I do believe this was not cockpit error on their part.

Comment: Thats bad then if you are sure it works, Then **REPORT** it.

Comment: may you post your sqlite helper class?

Comment: The SQLite stuff is all managed through an ORM tool called Sugar. 
 https://satyan.github.io/sugar/  I've also been reaching out to their development community.  Based on my initial feedback I do believe I'm using that tool correctly and it isn't a bug with the package.

Answer (score 0):

Play store updates do not do an uninstall and re-install in any situation, so that isn't the issue.

Whenever I've seen anything like this before it has been because of an issue with the [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) usage of the code. Possibly the user has been offline for a while, and missed a few intermediate updates. Then the code does a new create instead of a multiple step update in this situation.